# Installing MySQLDb python module *without* Internet Connection

Tags: python, django, module, mysql-python

Installing MySQLDb (Python module) *without* Internet Connection

Hi all,

I need to install MySQLDb on a SLES 11 Development Server. This Dev Server does not have access to the public internet due to corporate firewall policies. I was assuming this would merely be a nuisance which would force me to do source installations etc on things more easily installed otherwise. Instead, I have hit a wall, during my attempt to ultimately install and run Django with MySQL support.

I have downloaded and unzipped MySQL-python-1.2.4, and I am attempting to run its setup.py. However, any attempt to run setup.py, even just `sudo python setup.py --help`, reults in the following

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz
```

And then of course the download fails.

I downloaded and installed the current version of the `distribute` module (0.7.3), via `sudo python setup.py build install`. I assumed this would keep mysql-python's setup.py from trying to download `distribute`. But that does not appear to matter. I did have a quick look at mysql-client's setup.py to see where the download was being forced. It appears that its setup.py does this:

```
from distribute_setup import use_setuptools
use_setuptools()
```

Which calls this:

```
def use_setuptools(version=DEFAULT_VERSION, download_base=DEFAULT_URL,
                   to_dir=os.curdir, download_delay=15, no_fake=True):
    # making sure we use the absolute path
    to_dir = os.path.abspath(to_dir)
    was_imported = 'pkg_resources' in sys.modules or \
        'setuptools' in sys.modules
    try:
        try:
            import pkg_resources
            if not hasattr(pkg_resources, '_distribute'):
                if not no_fake:
                    _fake_setuptools()
                raise ImportError
        except ImportError:
            return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
```

And this, the import of pkg_resources fails (I have reproduced this from the command line); and the exception handler tries a download, which of course fails.

My understanding is that `distribute` is deprecated anyway, and that `setuptools` should be used instead. I do have `setuptools` installed; but is the mysqldb module hardcoded to use `distribute`, and possibly a specific version of `distribute`, and that's my issue? To be honest at this point I'm a bit confused about modules, dependencies, etc in Python (I'm quite mediocre at Python).

Thanks all,
Bean

Answer (score 1):

1. `git clone https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL or download tarball.` for mysqldb: `https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1`
2. `untar it`
3. `run sudo python setup.py install`

That's all.

Comment: Thanks ... but these look like instructions to install `pymysql`, not `mysqldb`. Since my goal is to run Django, and Django does not support `pymysql`, and since I followed https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/y-9CnQFMGtk et al to try and get Django working with `pymysql` but still have an ImportError, I'm afraid this answer is not 100% fit for my needs. Thank you though.

Comment: Also, I am still curious as to why the `mysqldb` setup.py attempts to download a version of `distribute`, despite 1. I already have installed the most recent `distribute` and 2. `distribute` has been obviated by `setuptools` and I have installed the most recent `setuptools` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Guess it's too late, but for the sake of the future googlers...

I had the same problem.  To solve it I had to comment these lines:

```python
if not hasattr(pkg_resources, '_distribute'):
            if not no_fake:
                _fake_setuptools()
            raise ImportError
```

After this I was able to install MySQL-python via `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question appears to be version dependent. [MySQLDb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) version 1.2.5 (newest version as of this writing) and later do not require distribute so `python setup.py install` will work.  Version 1.2.5 was released 01/2014 so this question is just that old.